# How to fix "ImportError: libgfortran.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory." in ubuntu 18.04 aarch64

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, apt-get

I am testing rknn api on my rk3399pro, which is arm64, ubuntu18.04.
I got libgfortran.so.5 importerror.

I try "apt-get install gfortran", but only has 4.7.4.0 version.
I try "find /usr -name libgfortran*".The result is:

```
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4.0.0
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/libgfortran.spec
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/libgfortran.a
/usr/share/doc/libgfortran4
/usr/share/doc/libgfortran-7-dev
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: I have fixed it.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libgfortran5-dbg

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install libgfortran5
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
pip install --upgrade scipy
```